# Combination of a standard random variable and a standard uniform random variable

Tags: gamma-distribution, uniform-distribution

**Edited**: Let $X$ be a Gamma distributed r.v., $X \sim\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ and $Y$ be a standard uniformly distributed r.v., $Y \sim U(0,1)$. Then what is the distribution of a r.v. $Z=XY$?

Comment: What is the _joint_ distribution of $X$ and $Y$? Also, regarding your hypothesized distribution for $XY$, what happens when $X < 0$?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate that's a very good point. I have made adjustments to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $X$ (the Gamma rv) and $Y$ (uniform rv) are independent, indicating with  $f_Z(z)$ the probability density function of the r.v. $Z$ for $z>0$, this is
$$
{f_Z}\left( z \right) = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\alpha  - 1,\frac{z}{\beta }} \right)}}{{\beta \,\, \Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)}}
$$ 
where $\Gamma \left( {\alpha  - 1,\frac{z}{\beta }}\right)$ is the incomplete Gamma function.
To find this result you need to apply the theory of Mellin transform. The probability density of the product of two independent random variables is given, in particular by the Mellin convolution of their densities expressed as
$$
{f_Z}(z) = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{s}{f_X}\left( {\frac{z}{s}} \right){f_Y}\left( s \right)ds}.
$$